# Populating Combobox with Query from MDF in VB.NET / Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am very new to Visual Studio...

I added a "Service-based Database" to my solution, which created an MDF file "Database1.mdf" in my project's directory. I created a table inside, "TTemplates", and I want to run a query to select the distinct values of a field inside to a combobox.

I tried creating a dataset, and made a table-adaptor which queries for the values I want shown on the combobox. But the examples I've seen then do something along the lines of:

```
Dim DS1 As New DataSet1
Me.TableAdapter.FillByName(DS1.myTable)
ComboBox1.DataSource=DS1.MyTable
ComboBox1.Displaymember="Company"
ComboBox.Valuemember="Company"
```

However, when I try this in Visual Studio, my combo-box doesn't seem to have any of these properties (datasource, displaymember, valuemember). They don't come up in intellisense.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I found a solution for this:

```
        Dim Con = New SqlConnection("INSERT CONNECTION STRING HERE")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Try
        If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = Con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table"


            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
            Do While dr.Read = True
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
            Loop

            Con.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

To get your connection string, go to Server Explorer, right-click the MDF file, and select Properties. Copy the Connection String property.